# Warning in RcppNumerical and RcppEigen on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: r, eigen, rcpp, numeric

Each time when I use RcppEigen or RcppNumerical I obtain a very long warning message in the console.

```
/home/Haache/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/RcppEigen/include/Eigen/src/Core/util/XprHelper.h:170:83: warning: ignoring attributes on template argument ‘Eigen::internal::packet_traits<double>::type {aka __vector(2) double}’ [-Wignored-attributes]
/home/Haache/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/RcppEigen/include/Eigen/src/Core/util/XprHelper.h:170:83: warning: ignoring attributes on template argument ‘Eigen::internal::unpacket_traits<__vector(2) double>::half {aka __vector(2) double}’ [-Wignored-attributes]
/home/Haache/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/RcppEigen/include/Eigen/src/Core/util/XprHelper.h:188:88: warning: ignoring attributes on template argument ‘Eigen::internal::packet_traits<double>::type {aka __vector(2) double}’ [-Wignored-attributes]
   typedef typename find_best_packet_helper<Size,typename packet_traits<T>::type>::type type;
                                                                                        ^~~~

In file included from /home/Haache/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/RcppEigen/include/Eigen/Core:430:0,
                 from /home/Haache/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/RcppEigen/include/Eigen/Dense:1,
                 from /home/Haache/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/RcppEigen/include/RcppEigenForward.h:30,
                 from /home/Haache/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/RcppEigen/include/RcppEigen.h:25,
                 from /home/Haache/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/RcppNumerical/include/RcppNumerical.h:10,
                 from PeerCount.cpp:3:
```

However, the code works well. I obtain this code for any code. The warning appears once I load

```
#include <RcppEigen.h>
```

or

```
#include <RcppNumerical.h>
```

All my packages are  up to date

Comment: The compiler tells you what to do do: add `-Wno-ignored-attributes` to your compiler flags.  And/or fix the Eigen code.  Your pick.  [ Also: never ever post screen shots when text logs would suffice. ]

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I edited my post. I just paste a part of the warning. However, Is it possible to explain more who to fix the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Dirk said in the comments you could add `-Wno-ignored-attributes` to your compiler flags. You can achieve that by creating the file `~/.R/Makevars` and adding

```
CXXFLAGS+=-Wno-ignored-attributes
CXX11FLAGS+=-Wno-ignored-attributes
CXX14FLAGS+=-Wno-ignored-attributes
```

Comment: just a note to add to this, if you wish these flags to be set for a particular package (so that it does not depend on your local R installation), you should edit `src/Makevars` to include `PKG_CXXFLAGS+=-Wno-ignored-attributes` etc. So note that it is `PKG_CXXFLAGS` instead of `CXXFLAGS`.

Comment: @JorisBierkens That's correct for local packages. Do not do this if you want to submit the package to CRAN, as the CRAN policy explicitly forbids flags that remove such warnings.